# Remove onclick effect after clicking on another img/button

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am making a small image area in my clients site, WHere I have some buttons under a big image. The big image changes onclick of bottom buttons. Now what I need is to make an effect of the selected button. It means Active effect. I can do this with a onclick function but it stays intact even if I click on other buttons.

So, Basically What I need is if you can tell me a way so that I can remove the onclick effect from image/button 1 when another image/button is clicked.

You can see the page here :
http://goo.gl/S1oVS

Comment: simply use unbind like if(...something..){ `$("whatever your selector").unbind('click')` }

Answer (score 1):

Use $('.class-selector').off('click'); to unbind click event on all elements with class 'class-selector' (or whatever selector you might have).

You can also do it in implementation of your click event as following:

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
  // Do something here...

  // Disable on click for this particular button, instead of all buttons.
  $(this).off('click');
});
```